# Apple watch HealthKit - unrecognized selector HKHealthStore startWorkoutSession:completion:

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, unrecognized-selector, healthkit

I try to get heart rate with watch OS2.0
I get this error when i try to start the workout session

```
Carleep WatchKit Extension[594:91719] -[HKHealthStore startWorkoutSession:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155b40e0
```

- I well added healthkit framework to my project.
- I added -all_load and -ObjC in Other linker flags
- I find this function in healthkit framework when i cmd+click on startWorkoutSession...
- I have iOS 9 and apple watch under watchOS 2.0

I succeed to request authorization for heartRate.
I don't know if i need force import of HKHealthstore+HKWorkout category, and i don't know how to do this.

If you have an idea about my problem and how to solve this it would be great.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, i just update Xcode 7 to the latest beta version (6). They removed the completion block in startworkoutsession in the last beta of watch os2. My sdk for watch os 2 in Xcode 7 beta 3 was outdated.

Comment: Can you please share your objective c code? Highly appreciated!

Comment: I take this project : https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate and i did it in objective-c. If you use objc i can add it ;)
My next problem is to find how access workout data even when apple watch screen is turn off.

Comment: Please add objective c code. Unfortunately it is getting harder and harder to get objective c code!

Comment: You can find my interface controller here :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rmd83xfiv3dxi94/AAAmuAoJfn49HOaTOkrLp_WBa?dl=0

And i found the solution to access heart rate data even when apple watch screen is turn off, i post the answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300247/access-workout-data-even-when-apple-watch-screen-turn-off/32308395#32308395

If you have any question don't hesitate ;)

Comment: I just created an "iOS App with WatchKit App" from the Xcode template. I am using Xcode 7.0 beta 6 and OS2.0 (13S5325c) . I switched "HealthKit to ON". If I start the app I do not get the authorisation for heart rate. Do I have to add something special? isHealthDataAvailable = True / HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate = True / requestAuthorizationToShareTypes = False

Comment: U need maybe provisionning profile in dev for all your targets (iPhone app, watchapp, watchextension) and you need 3 different appid for each provisionning profile

Comment: where do you ask for the auth.? Not in the InterfaceController.m file? I an other project I am asking on the iPhone app for the auth. which works fine. Which authoris. are needed?

    self.healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
    if ( ![self.healthStore authorizationStatusForType:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate]] ) {
        [self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate]] readTypes:[NSSet set] completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) { }