# Access workout data even when apple watch screen turn off

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I success to get heart rate data in live without workout session on apple watch os 2. But when apple watch screen turn off, my completion block is not anymore called. I would like to continue to manage these data in live and to make my phone ring when heart rate is too low.
Maybe i can let the app on the iphone perma open and maybe it can access to the healthkit data during this workout ?
Do you think this can work ? or do you have another idea ?

Regards

Comment: can you please let us know how did you get heart rate data in live without workout session? Did you place your code in watch kit extension or view controllers? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I explain everything in my answer just below ;). 
It is in the iphone app (view controllers) i do an HKAnchoredObjectQuery. 
I create a nstimer to call my request every 5s. There is a bug with iOS 9, when health iphone app is open, the request doesn't allow you to get latest heart rate data. You need to kill health native app before request these data in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is it possible to get the heart rate using HKWorkOutSession? Which one is better to fetch the heart rate continuously, HKAnchoredObjectQuery or HKWorkOutSession?

Comment: The heart rate data does not get stored in Health app from my Apple Watch. Can you please help me out with that?

Comment: You need to create a HKWorkOutSession and make HKAnchoredObjectQuery to get the data generate by this workout session.
You can see my interface controller here. I use almost the same HKAnchoredObjectQuery on my iphone app to get these data from iphone.
Try to kill health app and reopen it, you should see your heart rate data, but as i said you need to kill and not reopen this app to access heart rate data in live.

Comment: Hi Arsene, I did try that, but everytime I get ***Authorization not determined*** error. If I put a requestAuthorization block, then I never get a successful callback. Did you face any issue of that kind?

Comment: You need to implement applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization in appDelegate of your iphone app. You can find mine and my interface controllers here :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rmd83xfiv3dxi94/AAAmuAoJfn49HOaTOkrLp_WBa?dl=0

Comment: Hi Arsene, thanks a lot for your comment and source code. It helped a lot. However, ***applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization*** is not getting called in my AppDelegate file. Do I need to make any other configuration for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88586/discussion-between-dhaval-h-nena-and-arsene-huot).

Comment: Yea you need to activate in all your target healthkit capabilities. You will need also to create 3 appids and provisioning profile for all your targets (only in dev for a first time). Let me know if it's ok like this

Comment: Agree, but XCode manages the provisioning profiles and ids by itself. So I'm able to debug the things on watch and iPhone both. Still ***applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization*** is not getting called in my AppDelegate file

Comment: Hi Arsene thanks for the support, finally your suggestion worked and we are able to get the Heart Rates and Accelerometer values :)

Comment: Hi Dhaval Nena, what do you mean accelerometer values? Real time or hístorical ones? Which method did you use to get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey i found a solution :

i keep iphone app in foreground with :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

And with the same query than apple watch (HKAnchoredObjectQuery) i can access the latest health kit data. I well get live heart rate data even when my apple watch is turn off (with a workout session)

- my query

HKQuantityType *type = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];

```
HKAnchoredObjectQuery *heartRateQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc]
                                     initWithType:type
                                     predicate:nil
                                     anchor:self.anchor
                                     limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit
                                     resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable sampleObjects, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * _Nullable deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable newAnchor, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                         if (error) {

                                             // Perform proper error handling here...
                                             NSLog(@"*** An error occured while performing the anchored object query. %@ ***",
                                                   error.localizedDescription);

                                         }

                                         self.anchor = newAnchor;

                                         HKQuantitySample *sample = (HKQuantitySample *)[sampleObjects firstObject];
                                         if (sample) {
                                             double value = [sample.quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];

                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                                 self.heartrateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",value];
                                             });
                                             NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",value]);
                                             [self.hkStore stopQuery:heartRateQuery];


                                         }
                                     }];
```

[self.hkStore executeQuery:heartRateQuery];

Comment: How often do you get the callbacks on the iOS side? Cause for me it's only about every 30 minutes or so... (with all the samples that happened withing that time).  Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: @Arsene can you read the heart rate in real time with this approach?

Comment: @Licx i could get the heart rate every 5 seconds.

Comment: @ArseneHuot even when the watch screen goes off?

Comment: Yea just try the query just above. Put it in a function which will be call by a NSTimer in loop ;) It works until you stop your workout session, even if your apple watch screen goes off (that was one of my problematic as mentioned)
BUT you need to keep your iPhone application open and you can do it easily with [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES

Comment: @Arsene Huot Can you please post the code of WorkOut session here?

Answer (score 0):

By design, watchOS 2 apps are not allowed to run while the watch screen is off.  You cannot change this behavior.

Comment: Ok that's what i thought. 
Do you think i can keep the iphone app open and access the health kit data from my iphone (during the workout) ?

Comment: The user's phone is likely to be locked during the workout, and HealthKit data is not available when the device is passcode locked.  Also note that HealthKit data from the watch only syncs over to the phone periodically so it is not available in real time anyways.

Comment: Yea but with iphone app open and HKAnchoredObjectQuery  i succeed to get heart rate data in real time on my iphone (even if apple watch app is turn off). I had the problem of sync, but when i call [self.hkStore startQuery:heartRateQuery]; it works fine, i don't know very why but it seems to force import of data ...

More details in my answer ;)