# How can we get heart rate when apple watch in background in WatchOS 2.2

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I am very confuse not find any solution how can we get heart rate when app in foreground and background.

Comment: Then how 

Arsene Huot answer work according to him in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300247/access-workout-data-even-when-apple-watch-screen-turn-off?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Apps have no way of running in the background on watchOS 2, so you cannot query for heart rate when the Apple Watch screen is off.